# Why the result of calculating path size differs from calculating the same path, using du

Tags: python, linux, unix

I've made a script to calculate the size of current path.

```
def getFolderSize(path):
    total_size = os.path.getsize(path)
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(itempath):
            total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
        elif os.path.isdir(itempath):
            total_size += getFolderSize(itempath)
    return total_size
```

However, when I run `du` it shows me completely different result.

```
def du(path):
    return subprocess.check_output(['du','-sh', path]).split()[0].decode('utf-8')
```

How those two functions differs and what might cause such distinguish in results?

Comment: Some: 1) `du` counts the size of allocated blocks, `path.getsize()` returns only the file size (which maybe smaller). 2) you don't handle the size of  directories (those also consume space).

Comment: @dhke fixed the 2)
As for your first notice, actually du returns smaller result, than my custom function

Comment: `os.path.getsize()` returns the size in bytes. `du` reports the size in blocks. Sparse files will be smaller than their size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't skip symbolic links. If the link points to a file, it adds the size of the target file. If the link points to a directory, it recurses into that directory (which can potentially cause infinite recursion if it points to an ancestor directory). You should check for a link first.

```
def getFolderSize(path):
    total_size = os.path.getsize(path)
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.islink(itempath):
            pass
        elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
            total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
        elif os.path.isdir(itempath):
            total_size += getFolderSize(itempath)
    return total_size
```

There may still be some differences, though. `du` uses the size in disk blocks, `os.path.getsize()` returns the size in bytes. Files with large blocks of zero bytes may be "sparse", and the filesystem doesn't store them explicitly on the disk, so they won't be included in the `du` output. And `du` gets the size of symlinks, but there's no way to do that with the `os.path` methods (maybe there's a lower-level interface).